# Can we fail jenkins build if build.xml fails which is being called through a bat script

Tags: batch-file, groovy, ant, jenkins-pipeline

I am calling a batch file from `Jenkinsfile`. Through that batch file I am calling ant build.xml.

Currently though the ant build.xml is failing pipeline is executing next stage.

Is there any way to avoid this scenario?

Comment: Question is not clear, can you make it clear in description.

Answer (score 0):

For the case that you are using Jenkins declarative pipeline you could add thw following to let Jenkins skip the stages after one becomes unstable:

```
options
 {
  skipStagesAfterUnstable()
 }
```